# How can I add a callback when a new thread is being created in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, f#

I've got an ASP.NET Core HTTP-server running in .NET 5. A library that I'm using needs to be initialized once per thread. Ideally, I'd be able to add some kind of callback so that I can call the initialization code when the ASP.NET web server starts a thread. Does such a thing exist?

The reason for this is that I need to make calls into some old code in the OCaml runtime, and OCaml [requires each thread to be registered](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#ss:c-thread-register) to call into the OCaml runtime. I'm currently doing this once per request, but I want to do this as cheaply as possible instead.

**Update**: looks like ASP.NET uses the default .NET [threadpool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-5.0#definition). Don't know what to do with this info yet, but if there's a way to run this callback on all threads in the threadpool, that would work for me.

Comment: Why? Every request is served by a separate thread that comes from a thread pool. If you use IIS in-process deployment the pool is provided by IIS. Modifying a pooled thread (eg by changing its CultureInfo) can cause unexpected problems the next time it's used

Comment: You're using the `F#` tag, so it shouldn't be a surprise that immutability and injecting dependencies is preferable to modifying state. Instead of modifying the thread state you could write a middleware that applied the state you want on each request. Or you could *inject* the state you want - all BCL methods that are affected by locale accept a `CultureInfo` parameter, allowing them to work for any CultureInfo, not just the server's

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just answered the "why"

Comment: Why the F# tag if you're trying to use OCaml then? As for `cheaply` the cross-runtime call is probably already adding a *lot* of overhead. What you can do is *somehow* check if the other runtime is initialized - by storing something in thread local storage, or storing initialized thread IDs in a static queue. The best place to do that is a middleware, not the request itself.

Comment: Re The F# tag, I'm writing code in F#, using ASP.NET, and it's calling the old code (which is in OCaml) via C APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be an expensive problem and will not scale well (at all) if the initialization has any sort of resource allocation. However, there are many ways to acheive this, i.e. a concurrent dictionary of thread id, or another novel *thread safe* solution might be to use [`ThreadLocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=net-5.0).

**Nonsensical Example**

This is a contrived example, it's over-baked to only show that it works and is thread safe:

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<bool> ThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<bool>(() =>
{
   Thread.Sleep(100);
   // dll.init
   return true;
});

private static bool Check()
{
   if (!ThreadLocal.IsValueCreated)
   { 
      Console.WriteLine("starting thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      return ThreadLocal.Value;
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Already Started : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
   return false;
}
```

**Test**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   Task.Run(Check);

Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

```
starting thread : 8
starting thread : 4
starting thread : 5
starting thread : 6
starting thread : 7
starting thread : 9
starting thread : 10
starting thread : 11
Already Started : 4
Already Started : 6
```

**Update per comment**

Essentially `ThreadLocal` runs once **and only once** per thread.

To take this a step further, you could create a per request middleware class and add it to your pipeline:

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<bool> ThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<bool>(() =>
    {
       // dll.init
       // return anything you like
       return true;
    });
    
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) =>  _next = next;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // use the value if you need, do anything you like really
        var value = ThreadLocal.Value
        
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: I clarified the question to refect that I want to do this just once per thread, not on every request.

Comment: @PaulBiggar the dll only gets initialized one per thread. I have updated the answer

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thanks @TheGeneral!

Answer (score 1):

This technically doesn't answer your question, but you could have a List or hash or Dictionary of registered threads. Whenever your main method(s) are called, at the start do a check to see if that specific thread has been prepared yet.

```
private var threadFooDict = new Dictionary<int, ThreadSpecificFoo>();
public void Foo(){
    var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;//for the managed thread
    //var threadId = AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();//for the OS thread
    if(!threadFooDict.ContainsKey(threadId))
        threadFooDict[threadId] = new ThreadSpecificFoo();
    var thisFoo = threadFooDict[threadId];
}
```

Something like the above could possibly work. If you can't find a way to set up an initialization trigger this should be a decent enough workaround. If you do end up using my solution you should probably replace the dictionary with a concurrent dictionary or something else that's threadSafe.